# Ver rotas no CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Eu baixei um script de imobiliária que foi feita com o **CodeIgniter**, o problema é que estou tentando ver aonde fica os `controllers` e `views` dele, pois fui na pasta `application/controllers` e `application/views` e não tem nada, nenhum arquivo a não ser um `index.html` com conteúdo de 10 linhas no máximo (coisa boba). Pelo que vi ele está puxando da pasta `application/modules`, pois nessa página tem outras páginas como **account**, **admin**, **install**, etc. e dentro delas tem as pastas `controllers`, `models` e `views`. Gostaria de saber como isso é possível, redirecionar a pasta aonde pegará os controllers. Irei deixar os arquivos `index.php` e `routes.php` atual.

**index.php**

```
<?php
/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------
| DEFAULT TIMEZONE
|---------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Set the default timezone for date/time functions to use if
| none is set on the server.
|
*/

if( ! ini_get('date.timezone') )
{
   date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
}
/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION ENVIRONMENT
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * You can load different configurations depending on your
 * current environment. Setting the environment also influences
 * things like logging and error reporting.
 *
 * This can be set to anything, but default usage is:
 *
 *     development
 *     testing
 *     production
 *
 * NOTE: If you change these, also change the error_reporting() code below
 *
 */
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * ERROR REPORTING
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Different environments will require different levels of error reporting.
 * By default development will show errors but testing and live will hide them.
 */

if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
        break;

        case 'testing':
        case 'demo':
        case 'production':
            error_reporting(0);
        break;

        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * SYSTEM FOLDER NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * This variable must contain the name of your "system" folder.
 * Include the path if the folder is not in the same  directory
 * as this file.
 *
 */
    $system_path = 'system';

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION FOLDER NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * If you want this front controller to use a different "application"
 * folder then the default one you can set its name here. The folder
 * can also be renamed or relocated anywhere on your server.  If
 * you do, use a full server path. For more info please see the user guide:
 * http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html
 *
 * NO TRAILING SLASH!
 *
 */
    $application_folder = 'application';

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * DEFAULT CONTROLLER
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Normally you will set your default controller in the routes.php file.
 * You can, however, force a custom routing by hard-coding a
 * specific controller class/function here.  For most applications, you
 * WILL NOT set your routing here, but it's an option for those
 * special instances where you might want to override the standard
 * routing in a specific front controller that shares a common CI installation.
 *
 * IMPORTANT:  If you set the routing here, NO OTHER controller will be
 * callable. In essence, this preference limits your application to ONE
 * specific controller.  Leave the function name blank if you need
 * to call functions dynamically via the URI.
 *
 * Un-comment the $routing array below to use this feature
 *
 */
    // The directory name, relative to the "controllers" folder.  Leave blank
    // if your controller is not in a sub-folder within the "controllers" folder
    // $routing['directory'] = '';

    // The controller class file name.  Example:  Mycontroller
    // $routing['controller'] = '';

    // The controller function you wish to be called.
    // $routing['function'] = '';


/*
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  CUSTOM CONFIG VALUES
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * The $assign_to_config array below will be passed dynamically to the
 * config class when initialized. This allows you to set custom config
 * items or override any default config values found in the config.php file.
 * This can be handy as it permits you to share one application between
 * multiple front controller files, with each file containing different
 * config values.
 *
 * Un-comment the $assign_to_config array below to use this feature
 *
 */
    // $assign_to_config['name_of_config_item'] = 'value of config item';



// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// END OF USER CONFIGURABLE SETTINGS.  DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Resolve the system path for increased reliability
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 */

    // Set the current directory correctly for CLI requests
    if (defined('STDIN'))
    {
        chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
    }

    if (realpath($system_path) !== FALSE)
    {
        $system_path = realpath($system_path).'/';
    }

    // ensure there's a trailing slash
    $system_path = rtrim($system_path, '/').'/';

    // Is the system path correct?
    if ( ! is_dir($system_path))
    {
        exit("Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: ".pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));
    }

/*
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Now that we know the path, set the main path constants
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
    // The name of THIS file
    define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));

    // The PHP file extension
    // this global constant is deprecated.
    define('EXT', '.php');

    // Path to the system folder
    define('BASEPATH', str_replace("\\", "/", $system_path));

    // Path to the front controller (this file)
    define('FCPATH', str_replace(SELF, '', __FILE__));

    // Name of the "system folder"
    define('SYSDIR', trim(strrchr(trim(BASEPATH, '/'), '/'), '/'));


    // The path to the "application" folder
    if (is_dir($application_folder))
    {
        define('APPPATH', $application_folder.'/');
    }
    else
    {
        if ( ! is_dir(BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/'))
        {
            exit("Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: ".SELF);
        }

        define('APPPATH', BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/');
    }

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LOAD THE BOOTSTRAP FILE
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * And away we go...
 *
 */
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';

/* End of file index.php */
/* Location: ./index.php */
```

**routes.php**

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*

| -------------------------------------------------------------------------

| URI ROUTING

| -------------------------------------------------------------------------

| This file lets you re-map URI requests to specific controller functions.

|

| Typically there is a one-to-one relationship between a URL string

| and its corresponding controller class/method. The segments in a

| URL normally follow this pattern:

|

|   example.com/class/method/id/

|

| In some instances, however, you may want to remap this relationship

| so that a different class/function is called than the one

| corresponding to the URL.

|

| Please see the user guide for complete details:

|

|   http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

|

| -------------------------------------------------------------------------

| RESERVED ROUTES

| -------------------------------------------------------------------------

|

| There area two reserved routes:

|

|   $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';

|

| This route indicates which controller class should be loaded if the

| URI contains no data. In the above example, the "welcome" class

| would be loaded.

|

|   $route['404_override'] = 'errors/page_missing';

|

| This route will tell the Router what URI segments to use if those provided

| in the URL cannot be matched to a valid route.

|

*/



$route['default_controller'] = "en/show";

$route['404_override']       = "en/show/memento404";



$route['(:any)/agents'] = "(:any)/show/agent";

$route['(:any)/advancesearch'] = "(:any)/show/search";

$route['(:any)/results/(:any)'] = "(:any)/show/result/$2";

$route['(:any)/tags/(:any)'] = "(:any)/show/tag/$2";



$route['(:any)/property/(:any)'] = "(:any)/show/detail/$2";

$route['(:any)/embed/(:any)'] = "(:any)/show/embed/$2";



$route['(:any)/meme/(:any)'] = "(:any)/show/detail";

$route['(:any)/video/(:any)'] = "(:any)/tv/v";



/* End of file routes.php */

/* Location: ./application/config/routes.php */
```

Comment: Alisson, os arquivos postados não dizem muito. Vou dar uma olhada na documentação para ver se acho algo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este tipo de estrutura é conhecido como HMVC (Hierarquical Model-View-Controller).

É necessário utilizar a [Modular Extension](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc) para o CodeIgniter. [Tutorial aqui](http://developers.ph/codeigniter/hmvc-pattern-codeigniter-php-framework/).

Comment: É isso mesmo, HMVC. Me falaram no facebook a mesma coisa e li um tutorial para isso com CodeIgniter. Obrigado!